# How to properly sign out user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a made a ASP.NET membership provider, it works well but I notice that if the user changes passwords signs out and then tries to sign in again it fails, this also happends if the user has two or more accounts and signs out with one and tries to sign in with the other. If the user clears cookies in the browser he/she can sign in again, so it seems that when the user signs out the cookies are not deleted for some reason. Here is my sign out code:

```
void ClearAuthenticationCookie()
    {
        var cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, String.Empty) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) };
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);            
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        ClearAuthenticationCookie();

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

Comment: Can you recreate this problem on your development environment? `SignOut` should be enough

Comment: I can recreate it in the dev. env., I have stepped through all the membership provider code and asp:Login's call to 

public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)


returns true, but afterwards the membership provider public methods get a new call with a blank user name from asp:menu. I can also mention that if I just close the browser tab and open a new tab I can sign in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out now and it was really silly; the FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() from the sign out page puts /Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogout.aspx in the URL, so if you try to sign in it redirects back to the sign out page again. I should have seen this earlier, sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

try adding this on page load of your signout page:

```
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: I don't use sessions. enableSessionState is set to false.